# how to multiply columns and get their total using Knex.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

scenario: `order_items` *table contai*ning `quantity` and foreign key `product_id`  .
I am trying to join `product` table, and then multiply the `order_items.quantity` with `product.price`  and get the total sum of that.

does knex have support for built in column multiplication?

query:

```
await knex('order_items')
      .where('order_items.order_id', orderID)
      .leftJoin('products', 'order_items.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
      .sum('products.price * order_items.quantity')
```

output:

```
error column products.price not found
```

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have solved the issue.

```
 await knex('order_items')
      .where('order_items.order_id', orderID)
      .leftJoin('products', 'order_items.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
      .select(knex.raw('SUM ( products.price * order_items.quantity ) AS sum_total'))
```